# Writing helper : What's the use of the end arguments

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

Apologies for the name of the question, you will quickly understand what I mean.

On Ember website, if you follow the example given you will get the following :

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('fullName', function(person) {
  return person.get('firstName') + ' ' + person.get('lastName');
}, 'firstName', 'lastName');
```

But if you take out the end of the function it's still working :

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('fullName', function(person) {
  return person.get('firstName') + ' ' + person.get('lastName');
});
```

Is there any advantage, disadvantage to add/remove these values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first aproach have dependent keys, so if `firstName` or `lastName` is changed, the template is updated. The second just observe the person instance, not your properties.

Give a look in that [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/y82JC/) for further understanding

Comment: Thanks for the sharp answer.

Answer (score 2):

These values indicate the properties to which this helper is bound to. This means that if the values of these properties change the helper will be updated.
The following example demonstrates this ,

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/udOkupe/1

By pressing the test button the firstName value is changed, only one of the *fullName helpers* will be updated.

**hb**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    {{firstName}}<br/>
    {{lastName}}
    <br/>
    {{fullName this.model}}<br/>
    {{fullName2 this.model}}<br/>
    <button {{action "test"}}>test</button>
  </script>
```

**js**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  test:null,
  model: function() {
    this.set("test",App.Person.create({firstName:"my fname",lastName:"my lastname"}));
    return this.get("test");
  }
  ,
  actions:{
    test:function(){
      this.get("test").set("firstName","lallalal");
    }
  }
});

Ember.Handlebars.helper('fullName', function(person) {
  return "fullName:"+person.get('firstName') + ' ' + person.get('lastName');
}, 'firstName', 'lastName');
Ember.Handlebars.helper('fullName2', function(person) {
  return "fullName:"+person.get('firstName') + ' ' + person.get('lastName');
});

App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  firstName:"",
  lastName:""
});
```